# Python & spacy: Visualizing spans in a notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization, spacy

I am following the instructions of spacy in order to visulaize the spans in a notebook and copying the code :
https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#span

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.tokens import Span

text = "Welcome to the Bank of China."

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp(text)

doc.spans["sc"] = [
    Span(doc, 3, 6, "ORG"), 
    Span(doc, 5, 6, "GPE"),
]

displacy.serve(doc, style="span")
```

the result in my notebook is as follows:
[image]

it is weird that when using displacy.render the rendering is of another quality as when using "serve". Serve can not be used properly in a notebook.

I would like to know what I need to do to get the result shown in the documentation within a notebook. That means, the underlying.

NOTE: `display(displacy.render(doc, style="span"))` does not work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notebook you have to pass `jupyter=True` argument.

```
displacy.render(doc, style="span", jupyter=True)
```